# Is there python3 framework comparable to CodeIgniter for PHP?

Tags: codeigniter, frameworks, python-3.x

I am used to developing application using CodeIgniter (PHP), I would like to know is there any framework as flexible as CodeIgniter in python 3.X? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) (runs on Python 3 since version 0.5), [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/), (since 3.2) and [Pyramid](http://www.pylonsproject.org/) (in 1.3, out in alpha at the moment).

The are all small flexible frameworks. And I think they all use MVC too, like CodeIgniter.

Comment: as far as I know, bottle and cherrypy is micro-framework. they don't have MVC pattern. But it is still possible to have such a MVC in bottle. This one is an example: https://github.com/goFrendiAsgard/kokoropy

Answer (score 2):

We are on the same boat. And I think the answer is no, there aren't (yet).
I am also a PHP coder, and very familiar with CodeIgniter. Nowadays, people move to a "better" framework called Laravel. It has composer and namespace support.

For me, both of the features (namespace and composer) sounds like python's namespace and easy_install. So moving to python is a right decision (I hope)

As I can't find any framework which is as easy as CodeIgniter in both, python and PHP realm. I try to make one here https://github.com/goFrendiAsgard/kokoropy. It is still in the early stage of development, and it has CodeIgniter like design. Maybe it will also be useful for you.

Comment: Good job, goFrendiAsgard! I am also looking for a CodeIgniter-like framework written in python!